# How to inject one file into another with Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I have two files in my src/main/resources and I want one file's body to be injected into specific place of another file. So one file should be a template and another file will the data to fill this template (something like in Apache Velocity).

Can I do this with some existing Maven plugin?

Thank you in advance.

Solution:
I decided not to use a special plugin but to add this to pom.xml:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>rng-injection</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <echo message="Injecting RNG schemes"/>

                            <copy file="${main.resources}/RNG/enets-template.rng"
                                  tofile="${main.resources}/RNG/enets.rng"
                                  verbose="true"
                                  overwrite="true"/>

                            <copy file="${main.resources}/RNG/modeldefinition-template.rng"
                                  tofile="${main.resources}/RNG/modeldefinition.rng"
                                  verbose="true"
                                  overwrite="true"/>


                            <property name="enets-def" value="${main.resources}/RNG/enetsdefinitions.rng"/>
                            <loadfile property="def-file" srcfile="${enets-def}"/>
                            <replace file="${main.resources}/RNG/enets.rng">
                                <replacefilter token="{!enets-definition!}" value="${def-file}"/>
                            </replace>

                            <replace file="${main.resources}/RNG/modeldefinition.rng">
                                <replacefilter token="{!enets-definition!}" value="${def-file}"/>
                            </replace>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any plugin that provided what you want to do, but as a start you might be able to read the body into a property and use resource filtering to inject that property into the second file.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of how to build a plugin to do something related to this, see the collections codegenerator  mojo at Apache Mahout. It is a plugin that uses velocity to generate java code.